# Difference between Correlated Matrix and PCA?

Tags: correlation, pca, matrix

What's the difference between a simplex Correlated Matrix and a Principal Component Analysis? Or we can say that "Everytime that we do a PCA we generate a Correlated Matrix"

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A covariance matrix is the matrix of the covariance between features in your dataset. The PCA can use the covariance matrix to transform a set of linearly correlated into a set of linearly uncorrelated variables. The correlation $\mathrm{Corr}$ can be obtained directly from the covariance matrix $Cov$ by the following formula:
$$ \mathrm{Corr}_{i,j} = \frac{\mathrm{Corr}_{i,j}}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Corr}_{i,i}\mathrm{Corr}_{j,j}}}$$

Comment: PCA doesn't perform dimensionality reduction though.

Comment: Isn't it a dimensionaity reduction method ?

Comment: It isn't. You can apply post-hoc heuristics to achieve that, but dimensionality reduction isn't intrinsic to the ordinary PCA.

Comment: Thanks, so would it be right to say that selecting the two first components from the PCA analysis is performing dimensionality reduction although PCA by itsef is just a tool to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah, exactly :)

Comment: PCA is just the transformation from one space to another where the resulting variables are uncorrelated.

Comment: Cool I understand, I will correct my answer then

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between a simplex Correlated Matrix and a Principal Component Analysis?

One is a form of representing bivariate correlations between variables, the other is a projection to a space where its variables are linearly uncorrelated.

> Or we can say that "Everytime that we do a PCA we generate a
>   Correlated Matrix"

No, we can't, a covariance matrix eigen-decomposition is a theoretical necessity to perform PCA, but in practice one can achieve the same using SVD, so nowhere a covariance matrix is formed during the procedure.

Comment: What is "simplex Correlated Matrix"? Given that you answered the question containing this term, you probably know what it means.

Comment: @amoeba I assumed it was a typo, as it didn't look like it referred to the simplex method, and in the second time OP refers to it the term is absent.

Comment: Perhaps I judged wrong though...

Comment: Well, I was not sure what "Correlated Matrix" is either :)

Comment: I assumed typo on that one too tbh @amoeba